# Private post caught in endless redirect loop

Tags: posts, permalinks, post-meta

I have an old post set to private. When I visit it in a browser, Network in DevTools shows that it is endlessly redirecting to itself. I have switched off my redirect plugin, that didn't help.

I wondered if it was a canonical redirect, so I tried this in functions.php:

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

No success, so I tried:

```
remove_action('template_redirect', 'wp_old_slug_redirect');
```

And, **that has fixed it**. However, I then checked for old slugs:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_wp_old_slug'
```

There is no entry with the relevant post_ID?! How do I fix this one page?

Comment: What does the `wp_old_slug_redirect` function look like? Can you share the its code?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_old_slug_redirect/

Comment: Oh, I see! When it can't find an old slug with `_find_post_by_old_slug` it tries with `_find_post_by_old_date` and looks up `_wp_old_date` in the `wp_postmeta` - is that right?